# How qubit would allow parallel operations?

Tags: quantum-computer

Read [Why Quantum Computers Will Be Exponentially Faster Than Digital Computers](https://singularityhub.com/2017/09/18/why-quantum-computers-will-be-exponentially-faster-than-digital-computers/)

" Qubits can be both 1 and 0 simultaneously — meaning they can perform two calculations at once "

How 2 calculations (or 'N' calculations) will be performed at once by quantum computer?

Comment: Obligatory SMBC: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3

Comment: @MarkMitchison Not fully clear yet, but helped a lot.

Comment: Well the important message to take away is that qubits *don't* allow parallel operations, or rather that is not a useful way of understanding quantum computing.